# Convergence of improper integral with logarithm

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I would like to determine the nature of $A$ without calculating it.
$$
A= \int_0^1 \ln(1-t^{a}) dt  .
$$

In $t=1$ we have a problem, so how should I proceed?

Comment: When $t=0$ there is no problem; you probably meant when $t=1$.

Comment: Not only does the integral converge, for $a>0$, but it represents the formula which extends [harmonic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Special_values_for_fractional_arguments) to non-natural arguments. $A=-H_{1/a}$

Answer (score 4):

Let $u=1-t$ then

$$\ln(1-t^a)=\ln(1-(1-u)^a)=_0\ln(1-1+au+o(u))\sim_0\ln(au)$$
and since the integral $\int_0^1\ln xdx $  is  convergent then the given integral is also convergent for all $a>0.$